# Python Type Error raised during savefig in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a python script that uses a pandas dataframe and matplotlib to create some plots.  Previously the script worked fine with no 'depreciated' or 'future warnings'. I wasn't using the very latest python, numpy, matplotlib etc. but was within about 1 year old,  eg: pandas ~0.9, Python 3.7.5.  I was forced to reinstall windows so just did a pip install to get the packages i needed, so they are all current now. However with the latest packages I am now getting an exeption when the following code runs.

Exception has occurred: TypeError
must be real number, not str"

It is being thrown when the code to save the figure is called:

```
fig.savefig(rf'{cfg.output_dir}plots/data_gaps.png', dpi=100, format='png', transparent=True)
```

However i cant see anything in that line that is being given a string when it expects a int or float.  I even tried simplifying the code to simply:
`fig.savefig('data_gaps.png')` Still throws the error, so i assume its coming from when the fig is being constructed.

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=int(len(gap_list)), ncols=1, figsize=(12,int(fig_size(gap_list))), sharex=True)
    fig.suptitle('Recording Gaps')

    for ch in gap_list:
        i = gap_list.index(ch)
        resample_s = 4*ch_gap[ch]['rec_rate']
        ylabel = ch + ' (' + ch_gap[ch]['board'] +') - '+ ch_gap[ch]['unit']
        data = df[ch].resample(f'{resample_s}s').mean()
        is_nan = data.isnull()
        # if `ax` is a numpy array then index it, else just use `ax`
        ax_i = ax[i] if isinstance(ax, np.ndarray) else ax
        ax_i.fill_between(data.index, 0, (is_nan*data.max()), color='r', step='mid', linewidth='0', alpha=0.5)
        ax_i.plot(data.index, data, color='b', linestyle='-', marker=',', label=ylabel)
        ax_i.legend(loc='upper left')
```

fig_size() is a function that returns an appropriate figure height based on the size of the gap_list list. I tried casting that as int and just hardcoding a number it still throws the error. Can anyone see where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As usual Python was telling why it didn't work:

linewidth='0', changed the width from a string to an int, linewidth=0

I guess the previous version of matplotlib was automatically fixing this for me without raising an warning or exception.